# What should I use to open windows explorer in different positions?

Tags: c#, windows-explorer

I recently posted this question but didn't get any response on it: 
[Need help opening 2 windows explorer windows to two different spots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356595/need-help-opening-2-windows-explorer-windows-to-two-different-spots)
I still would like any help that can be given in this case. One thing that I thought might have been confusing about my previous post is that both of the examples I noted were using SetWindowPos. I really don't care about the method used to solve this problem only that A) it uses c# and B) that it meets the desired criteria as posted in my previous post. Please, if there is further clarification needed please ask me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mouse. Click the corner of the window and drag it until it is the desired size.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making myself clear, or maybe you didn't read that I said I needed to do this with c#. Some HONEST help would be very much appreciated.